# $\omega$-consistency and related terms

Tags: logic, terminology, incompleteness

We know that a theory $T$ is $\omega$-*inconsistent* if there is a formula $\psi$ such that $T$ proves $(\exists x)\psi(x)$, and $T$ also proves $\lnot \psi(n)$ separately for each standard natural number $n$. 
So $T$ is $\omega$-*consistent* if it is not $\omega$-inconsistent.

Is there a name for the following property: if for every formula $\psi$ such that $\psi(0), \psi(1), \psi(2),...$ can be proven in $T$, then $\forall x \psi(x)$ can be proven in $T$ ?

And what is the connection between this property and $\omega$-inconsistency / consistency?

Thank you.

Comment: Can a consistent theory satisfy this? I mean, if $T$ is stronger than PA, and it's consistent, then for every $n$ it proves $\phi(n)$ where $\phi(x)$ is the statement that $x$ is not the Gödel number of a proof of a contradiction from $T$. If $T$ satisfied this, it would necessarily also prove that $\forall n\phi(n)$ - that is, it will prove its own consistency, which is a contradiction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my Gödel book §21.6, I give the following definition, which I took/take to be pretty standard terminology:

> An arithmetic theory $T$ is $\omega$-incomplete iff, for some open wff $\varphi\mathsf{(x)}$, $T$ can prove each $\varphi\mathsf{(\overline{m})}$ but $T$ can't go on to prove  $\forall \mathsf{x}\varphi\mathsf{(x)}$.

So if $T$ *is* able to prove $\forall \mathsf{x}\varphi\mathsf{(x)}$ when $T$ can prove each $\varphi\mathsf{(\overline{m})}$, for any $\varphi\mathsf{(x)}$,  then $T$ would  (as Luca says) naturally be called $\omega$-complete.

What is the connection between $\omega$-incompleteness  and $\omega$-inconsistency? Well, we can say this:

> $\omega$-incompleteness in a theory of arithmetic is a regrettable weakness; if $T$ can prove each $\varphi\mathsf{(\overline{m})}$ it would be very nice if $T$ were always able to prove $\forall \mathsf{x}\varphi\mathsf{(x)}$ too. Sadly, Gödel's incompleteness theorem tells us that, surprisingly, nice enough theories $T$ can't be *this* nice! By contrast $\omega$-inconsistency is not just a regrettable weakness but a Very Bad Thing indeed (not quite as bad as outright inconsistency, maybe, but still bad). For evidently, a theory that can prove each of $\varphi\mathsf{(\overline{m})}$ and yet also prove $\neg\forall \mathsf{x}\varphi\mathsf{(x)}$ is just not going to be interpretable as being about the natural numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The rule you're referring to is called *$\omega$-rule*, and if you add it to the axioms and rules of inference of first-order logic you get the so called *$\omega$-logic*. Thus I would say that the name you're looking for is *consistent with the $\omega$-rule*, or *consistent in $\omega$-logic*. A shorter name is *$\omega$-complete*.

A theory $T$ has an $\omega$-model if and only if it is consistent in $\omega$-logic (see Proposition 2.2.13 in C. C. Chang and H. Jerome Keisler's *Model Theory*). It follows that consistency with the $\omega$-rule implies $\omega$-consistency, but it is actually a stronger condition.

Comment: I believe the property in the original question is that the theory is *closed under* the $\omega$-rule.