# Does '$\omega$-consistency' mean to be consistent with $\Omega$?

Tags: logic

In a strong enough meta-logic such as ZFC or CC, for any $L_{\Omega}$-theory $T$, is $\Omega \models T$ equivalent to that $T$ is $\omega$-consistent?

Here, $L_{\Omega}$ is a first-order language whose signature is $\left\langle + , \cdot , S , 0 , < \right\rangle$, and $\Omega$ is the standard model of $L_{\Omega}$.

Comment: What is $L_\Omega$, and what is $\Omega$? Please edit your question to give more context.

Comment: @AlexKruckman $L_{\Omega}$ is a first-order language whose signature is $\left\langle + , \cdot , S , 0 , < \right\rangle$, and $\Omega$ is the standard model of $L_{\Omega}$.

Comment: Ok - Please edit your question to include these important details. I think this notation is very unusual: I've never seen the standard model ($\omega$ or $\mathbb{N}$) referred to as $\Omega$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Jobs done. I meant $\Omega = \left\langle \mathbb{N} , +_{\mathbb{N}} , \times_{\mathbb{N}} , S_{\mathbb{N}} , 0_{\mathbb{N}} , <_{\mathbb{N}} \right\rangle$, i.e., $\left| \Omega \right| = \omega$.

Comment: See [$\omega$ ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Successor_and_limit_ordinals) and [$\omega$-consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory#Definition)

Comment: As you see from the linked def, the notation originates with $\omega$-**in**consistency that is a sort of "inconsistency at infinity", that needs the capability of the theory to "represent" natural numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. This is explained (but not very clearly, I think) on the Wikipedia page for [$\omega$-consistent theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory).

Let $L$ be a language containing $L_A = \{+,\cdot,S,0,<\}$, the language of arithmetic. Let $T$ be an $L$-theory.

- We say $T$ is $\omega$-inconsistent if there is an $L$-formula $\varphi(x)$ in one free variable $x$ such that $T\vdash \varphi(n)$ for every term $n = S(S(\dots S(0)\dots ))$ representing a natural number, but $T\vdash \lnot \forall x\,\varphi(x)$. Otherwise, we say $T$ is $\omega$-consistent.
- $\omega$-logic is first-order logic extended with the infinitary rule with hypotheses $\varphi(0)$, $\varphi(1)$, $\varphi(2)$, $\dots$ and conclusion $\forall x\, \varphi(x)$. We say $T$ is consistent in $\omega$-logic if $T$ does not prove a contradiction in $\omega$-logic.
- We say $T$ has an $\omega$-model if there is a model $M\models T$ such that the underlying set of $M$ is $\omega$, and the symbols of $L_A$ are interpreted in the standard way on $\omega$. In the setting of your question, where $T$ is an $L_A$-theory, the only $\omega$ model is $\omega$ itself (with the symbols of $L_A$ interpreted in the standard way). So $T$ has an $\omega$-model if and only if $\omega\models T$.

Now $T$ has an $\omega$-model if and only if $T$ is consistent in $\omega$-logic, and these conditions imply that $T$ is $\omega$-consistent. But the converse is not true: there are $\omega$-consistent theories $T$ which are not consistent in $\omega$-logic, and hence have no $\omega$-model. An example is given in the section "Arithmetically unsound, $\omega$-consistent theories" on Wikipedia: $\mathsf{PA}+\lnot \omega\mathsf{-ConPA}$, where $\omega\mathsf{-ConPA}$ is the sentence asserting that $\mathsf{PA}$ is $\omega$-consistent.

See also the discussion on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2019758/7062) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/466465/7062).

Comment: Thank you! My question started by wondering why the term '$\omega$-consistency' refers to $\omega$-consistency. Now, I conclude: as consistency is to the guarantee of a model, $\omega$-consistency is to the guarantee of an $\omega$-model.